# Linker not constructing user-defined types

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker

I've got a long term project on the go that involves building an expert system that can generate novel musical harmonies. I began in VB.net took the project so far but wanted to use a platform independent language so I turned to c++ to facilitate future migration. Essentially tones are the atoms which when grouped as vectors form part of chord progressions which when grouped as vectors form part of blocks etc. So the whole structure has a recursive feel to it. Although the following code will both compile and link in Netbeans 7.2 I had terrible memory issues which were difficult to sort out so I am with Eclipse right now. Whilst the dynamic libraries will compile in Eclipse there seem to be linking issues on a gross level such that objects are not being created. I've spent literally days trying all sorts of remedies. I include here the top level main code and a part listing of the error messages I'm getting. Any pointers as to what might be going on would be appreciated. Thx in anticipation..

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Creative
 *
 * Created on August 6, 2012, 10:49 AM
 */

#include "../tonestatdynlib/name_pitchstructure.h"
#include "../sequencerdynlib/chord.h"
#include "../sequencerdynlib/Move.h"
#include "../sequencerdynlib/block.h"
#include "../sequencerdynlib/prog.h"
#include "../legalitydynlib/testLegal.h"
#include "../dataWriterdynlib/dWriter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>//database facility

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int make;
    char start;

    cout << "Do you want to start a new movement? Y/N" << endl;

cin >> start;

    if (start == 'Y') {
        bool end = false;
        Move theMove;
        block theBlock;
        prog theProg;
        int i = 1, mv = 1, bk = 1, pr = 1;

        theMove.items.push_back(theBlock);
        theBlock.items.push_back(theProg);

        do {
            chord nextChord(i);
            nextChord.getPitches();
            theProg.items.push_back(nextChord);
            dWriter dW(nextChord, pr, bk, mv, "SONO");
            cout << "Chord Number " << i << " is completed. Do you want to:" << endl;
            cout << "Enter another chord?:  1" << endl;
            cout << "Start a new progression?: 2" << endl;
            cout << "Start a new block?: 3" << endl;
            cout << "Start a new movement?: 4" << endl;
            cout << "Exit SONO: 5" << endl;
            cin >> make;
            switch (make) {
                case 5: end = true;
                    break;
                case 1: i++;
                    break;
                case 2: i = 1;
                    pr++;
                    break;
                case 3: i = 1;
                    pr = 1;
                    bk++;
                    break;
                case 4: i = 1;
                    pr = 1;
                    bk = 1;
                    mv++;
                    break;
            }
        } while (end == false);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error messages:

```
g++ -L"/Users/Creative/Documents/workspace/tonestatdynlib/Debug" -L"/Users/Creative/Documents/workspace/chordOpsdynlib/Debug" -L"/Users/Creative/Documents/workspace/dataWriterdynlib/Debug" -L"/Users/Creative/Documents/workspace/legalitydynlib/Debug" -L"/Users/Creative/Documents/workspace/sequencerdynlib/Debug" -L"/Users/Creative/Documents/workspace/tonestatdynlib" -L"/Users/Creative/Documents/workspace/sequencerdynlib" -L"/Users/Creative/Documents/workspace/legalitydynlib" -L"/Users/Creative/Documents/workspace/dataWriterdynlib" -L"/Users/Creative/Documents/workspace/chordOpsdynlib" -o "SONO"  ./main.o  



Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "block::block(block const&)", referenced from:
      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<block>::construct(block*, block const&)in main.o
      void std::_Construct<block, block>(block*, block const&)in main.o
      std::vector<block, std::allocator<block> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<block*, std::vector<block, std::allocator<block> > >, block const&)in main.o
  "prog::prog(prog const&)", referenced from:
      void std::_Construct<prog, prog>(prog*, prog const&)in main.o
      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<prog>::construct(prog*, prog const&)in main.o
      std::vector<prog, std::allocator<prog> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prog*, std::vector<prog, std::allocator<prog> > >, prog const&)in main.o
  "chord::chord(chord const&)", referenced from:
      void std::_Construct<chord, chord>(chord*, chord const&)in main.o
      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<chord>::construct(chord*, chord const&)in main.o
      std::vector<chord, std::allocator<chord> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<chord*, std::vector<chord, std::allocator<chord> > >, chord const&)in main.o
  "pitchStats::pitchStats(pitchStats const&)", referenced from:
      void std::_Construct<pitchStats, pitchStats>(pitchStats*, pitchStats const&)in main.o
  "block::~block()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      std::vector<block, std::allocator<block> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<block*, std::vector<block, std::allocator<block> > >, block const&)in main.o
  "prog::~prog()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      std::vector<prog, std::allocator<prog> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prog*, std::vector<prog, std::allocator<prog> > >, prog const&)in main.o
  "chord::~chord()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      std::vector<chord, std::allocator<chord> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<chord*, std::vector<chord, std::allocator<chord> > >, chord const&)in main.o
  "Move::Move()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "block::block()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "prog::prog()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "chord::chord(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "chord::getPitches()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "dWriter::dWriter(chord const&, int, int, int, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "dWriter::~dWriter()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Move::~Move()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [SONO] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only providing the paths in which to search for libraries to link to. You also need to provide the libraries, using `-l`. For example, for `libFoo.so` use `-lFoo`.

Comment: Important note about this: The libraries should be placed _after_ object files.

Comment: Thanks 4 YR reply juanchopanza that sorted the problem!

Comment: @Kam Good! If it fixed the problem, you can accept the answer by clicking on the tick-shaped icon.